# Issue while fetching the title from an ahref

Tags: php, preg-match, preg-match-all

I am trying to get the title from an a href.

My code returns all the a href string with inner text.

```
<h2 class="post-title entry-title">
<a href="www.anewdomain.com">I want to get this title</a>
</h2>

preg_match_all("/<h2 class='post-title entry-title'>(.*?)<\/h2>/s", $result1, $matches1, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
$my_title =$matches1[1][0][0];
echo $my_title;
```

Thanks guys!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
preg_match_all("/<h2 class='post-title entry-title'>(.*?)<\/h2>/s", $result1, $matches1, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
$my_title =strip_tags($matches1[1][0][0]);
echo $my_title;
```

It may solve your issue.. As you mentioned `$matches1[1][0][0]` returns the whole anchor tag, so just stripped it..!!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$source = '<a href="examplez.com">THIS I WANT TO GET</a>';
preg_match("'<a href=\"examplez.com\">(.*?)</a>'si", $source, $match);
if($match) echo $match[1];
```